# Converting to/getting original list object from string representation of original list object in python

Tags: python

I want to convert string representation of arbitrary list back to the original-like list object as explained in the code below:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list1str = str(list1) 
str2list1 = list1str[1:-1].split(",") #stripping off square brackets from [1,2,3,4] and then splitting
print(list1)      #[1,2,3,4]
print(str(list1)) #[1,2,3,4]
print(str2list1)  #['1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 4']    
                  #Notice that the elements are of string types. 
                  #Also there is a prefix empty space in ' 2' (and also in ' 3' and ' 4')
                  # --> I will like str2list1 to be ['1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 4']
```

Also if we are dealing with nested lists:

```
list2 = [1,2,['a','b'],4]
list2str = str(list2)
str2list2 = list2str[1:-1].split(",")
print(list2)      #[1, 2, ['a', 'b'], 4]
print(str(list2)) #[1, 2, ['a', 'b'], 4]
print(str2list2)  #['1', ' 2', " ['a'", " 'b']", ' 4']
                  # --> I will like str2list2 to be [1, 2, ['a', 'b'], 4]
```

How can I get exact the original list from its string representation?

Comment: if your list items are integers then you can also leverage `map(int, list1)` in python2.x

Comment: I suspect this is an XY problem that can be solved using the `json` module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("[1,2,['a','b'],4]")
[1, 2, ['a', 'b'], 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, use *eval()*:

```
lst = "[1, 2, 3, 4, ['a', 'b'], 5, 6]"
newlst = eval(lst)
```

so the newlst will be the exact python list you want

```
print (newlst)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, ['a', 'b'], 5, 6]
```

There's one more way to do what you want with *exec()*:

```
exec("newlst = {}".format(lst))
```

exec will actually treat the string as a python command/syntax.

Comment: will this work for other types too? tuples, dict etc.?

Comment: any kind of string can be used. just make sure the string is actual represented in a proper pythonic object.

Comment: @Abhishek You should be using `ast.literal_eval`, `eval` is dangerous: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: It will be correct to say that its _strong_ rather than dangerous, i guess.